# How to show message from resources with special characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to show messages in alerts from resources in mvc,
which contains special characters too in which double quotes or single quotes also comes and it generate me jquery error of quotes if my alert message in double quotes or in single quotes.

Comment: Then mask those special characters as required for your generated code to be valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a problem. Try to use HTML encoded symbols on you resource side - [link](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Double quote is `&#34;`, single - `&#39;`

Answer (score 1):

for single quotes and double quotes use valid html codes. like this

```
single quotes start =&lsquo;
single quotes end  =&rsquo;
double quotes start =&ldquo;
double quotes end = &rdquo;
```

see this output

> single quotes start =‘
>
> single quotes end  =’
>
> double quotes start =“
>
> double quotes end = ”

Answer (score 0):

try using System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(mvcResourceMessage);